# XAMPP issue - localhost showing unwanted "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp

I have installed xampp and when I access `http://localhost` on the browser, I get this screen:

[image]

I created a file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index.php, but when I access `http://localhost/project` or `http://localhost/project/index.php`, it gives 404 Error (page not found). Which makes me believe that localhost is not pointing to my xampp folder.

I tried to uninstall xampp, but even after uninstalling it, when I access localhost I get the same page.

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on? Or how I can debug it?

Comment: Can you provide your httpd.conf file ?

Comment: @Hritik - There isn't one as I have uninstalled it. Note that this screen shows up even when xampp is not installed in my machine. - Do you know how I can find out where localhost links?

Comment: Seems like it has left apache on your machine, check your installed programs and and the services running.

Answer (score 1):

First Stop the apache server using below command

sudo srevice apache2/ stop

after that restart the apache server using below command

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Answer (score 0):

Stop the apache server:

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

Start XAMPP:

> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Answer (score -1):

If you connect your network by proxy, which is located on Ubuntu, Proxy Server's xampp page will be shown.
If you add the localhost to proxy's except address list, you can see your local computer's xampp page.